# Error on foreach Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table cleaner, and a table called timeconfirmation with column called cleaner id, with a foreign key back to the id column in cleaner.
Here is the code I am getting an error by second loop, Cannot access a disposed object. I can't figure out what I did wrong?

```
@foreach (var c in Model.Cleaners)
                {        
                      @foreach (var p in c.TimeConfirmations)
                      {
                        <span>@p.id</span>
                      }          
              }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are getting the list of cleaners are you loading the TimeConfirmations with it? If you are using linq to sql just do something like this

```
  var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
            loadOptions.LoadWith<Cleaner>(c => c.TimeConfirmations);
            context.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You Got it on the button! I can't believe I missed this! Can't thank you enough!!!!